# how to track all the voice calls of the Android mobile?

Tags: android

how  to track all the voice calls of the android  mobile?
i have to  do this through android programming.
any ideas?

Comment: Android specifically? Or just any old mobile phone?  For 2 different phones, you will probably get 2 different answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `android.provider.CallLog.Calls` [API here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html)

- There is a nice post with a full example here: http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_querying_and_displaying_the_calllog-t169.html
- And another, less complete example here: http://dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/25-android-tutorial-call-logs

To begin with content providers, you can refer to:

- The android dev guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html
- post 1: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-iv-android-content-providers/
- post 2: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-part-10.html